# Strange issue returning value from array in session handling

Tags: php, session, http-headers

I have the following snipet from my session class. The whole MVC is PSR based you will find similarities in here.

```
private function getFingerprint()
{
    $headers = $this->registry->get('request')->getHeaders();
    $server = $this->registry->get('request')->getServer();

    $hash = '';

    if (true === isset($headers['User-Agent'])) {
        $hash .= $headers['User-Agent'];
    }
    // if (true === isset($headers['Accept'])) {
    //     $hash .= $headers['Accept'];
    // }
    // if (true === isset($headers['Accept-Encoding'])) {
    //     $hash .= $headers['Accept-Encoding'];
    // }
    // if (true === isset($headers['Accept-Language'])) {
    //     $hash .= $headers['Accept-Language'];
    // }
    // if (true === isset($headers['Accept-Charset'])) {
    //     $hash .= $headers['Accept-Charset'];
    // }
    if (true === isset($server['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $hash .= inet_ntop(inet_pton($server['REMOTE_ADDR']) & inet_pton('255.255.0.0'));
    }

    return hash('sha512', $hash);
}
```

After this I compare the returned value with the stored one the test method is irrelevant I get the same behaviour:

`strcmp($_SESSION['session.fingerprint'], $this->getFingerprint()) !== 0`

The problem lies around and afterwards:

```
if (true === isset($headers['Accept'])) {
    $hash .= $headers['Accept'];
}
```

All the required values are available multiple times checked. I got false positives when any of the commented parts get uncommented. Does somebody met such a strange behaviour? I am using Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.0f PHP/7.1.7 all x64 and TS versions.

Edit 1: The same strange behaviour is seen on PHP/5.6.31 too. It should be something in my code, if anybody reading this need source I can provide.

Edit 2: Working example of getFingerprint() which does not cause strange behaviour:

```
private function getFingerprint()
{
    $headers = $this->registry->get('request')->getHeaders();
    $server = $this->registry->get('request')->getServer();

    $hash = '';

    if (true === isset($headers['User-Agent'])) {
        $hash .= $headers['User-Agent'];
    }

    if (true === isset($server['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $hash .= inet_ntop(inet_pton($server['REMOTE_ADDR']) & inet_pton('255.255.0.0'));
    }

    return hash('sha512', $hash);
}
```

Comment: Your test method is not irrelevant, it's the bread and butter of this question. Please add it to your question.

Comment: I am not doing anything fance except `session_regenerate_id(true);` regenerating session id and removing old data. The comparison I use currently is the same as I wrote in my question. I admit that using only User-Agent and IP values works, tested many times. But I thought I'll spice up a little bit with some more user identificable values from the request. This is what doesn't work sadly.

Comment: Do you also change `$_SESSION['session.fingerprint']` when you add other line to `getFingerprint()`?

Comment: Yes it will be set during that process, you can take a look at the session class here: https://pastebin.com/LbfpwbzB